# Matrix dimensions must agree min max normalization?

Tags: matlab, normalization

Hi I get the error stated below, im trying to normalize between 0 and 1. The error I get is this:

```
columns =

     6

    ??? Error using ==> minus
    Matrix dimensions must agree.

    Error in ==> Kmeans at 54
        data = ((data-minData)./(maxData));
```

Not sure what ive did wrong? Full code below:

```
%% dimensionality reduction 
    columns = 6
    [U,S,V]=svds(fulldata,columns);

%% randomly select dataset
rows = 1000;
columns = 6;

%# pick random rows
indX = randperm( size(fulldata,1) );
indX = indX(1:rows);

%# pick random columns
indY = randperm( size(fulldata,2) );
indY = indY(1:columns);

%# filter data
data = U(indX,indY);

%% apply normalization method to every cell
maxData = max(data);
minData = min(data);
data = ((data-minData)./(maxData));
```

The dataset is 1000x6.

Comment: What is `size(data)`, and what is `size(minData)`?

Comment: Also, your error message ("`minVec`") doesn't match your code ("`minData`").

Comment: Hi Sorry Oli made a change just after I posted. Corrected now. P.s the dataset is 1000x6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Matlab documentation on `min`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/min.html):

> If `A` is a matrix, `min(A)` treats the columns of `A` as vectors, returning a row vector containing the minimum element from each column.

If you want to find the global minimum of a matrix, use either of the following forms:

```
min(min(A))
min(A(:))
```

Comment: Thank you Oli! Not sure if max min is better than my previous way `data = data./repmat(sqrt(sum(data.^2)),size(data,1),1);`